# How to last record value based on column if it empty or none get last-1

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

In Djnago, how to last record value based on column if it empty or none get last-1  element until record column value in not empty or none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) and [last](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#last):

```
YourModel.objects.exclude(fieldname__isnull=True).exclude(fieldname__exact='').last()
```